# Apparent problem with string substitution when using bquote and atop in mulit-line label

Tags: r, ggplot2, multiline

I'm trying to create multi-line label in which the first line is a character string and the second line is an expression.  I have searched through the archive and don't see any questions that seem to deal with the same problem.  I create the first line using paste and then pass it to atop as shown the example code below:

```
testIt <- function(){
library(ggplot2)

aPP   <- 100.1
firstLine <- paste("Areal Production = ",aPP,sep="")
pbase <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg))
p     <- pbase +
        geom_point() +
        labs(x=bquote(atop(firstLine, ~(mgC/m^2/day))),
             y="Foo")
print(p)
}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

I don't understand why the string I put into the variable named "firstLine" wasn't used and rather the variable name itself is in the label.

Maybe I have the order of the bquote and atop wrong??  Maybe I'm misusing atop?  I've tried all sorts of combinations but nothing seems to work for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It needs `.(objectname)` in `bquote` - according to `?bquote`

> bquote quotes its argument except that terms wrapped in .() are evaluated in the specified where environment.

```
testIt <- function(){
library(ggplot2)

aPP   <- 100.1
firstLine <- paste("Areal Production = ",aPP,sep="")
pbase <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg))
p     <- pbase +
        geom_point() +
        labs(x=bquote(atop(.(firstLine), ~(mgC/m^2/day))),
             y="Foo")
print(p)
}
```

-testing

```
testIt()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I did see that answer but frankly, I did not understand it.  Your solution is exactly what I needed.